# How can I add and remove authorised users from web.config location path in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.5

I am trying to add and remove authorised users from web.config programmatically. I am using Windows Authentication.

This is what I have on web.config

```
  <location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="domain\user1, domain\user2"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Now in the code I have the following code.

```
protected void UpdateUsers()
{
    System.Configuration.Configuration config = (Configuration)WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    ConfigurationLocationCollection section = config.Locations;

    foreach (ConfigurationLocation location in section)
    {
        if(location.Path == "Admin")
        {
            AuthorizationSection admin_section = (AuthorizationSection)config.GetSection("system.web/authorization");

            AuthorizationRule thisAuth = new AuthorizationRule(AuthorizationRuleAction.Allow) ;
                thisAuth.Users.Add("domain\\username");

             admin_section.Rules.Add(thisAuth);
             admin_section.CurrentConfiguration.Save();
        }

    }
}
```

The above code is adding the section on the system.web and not on the admin location.

Comment: If you edit your web.config, everyone who is currently connected to the site will be kicked out (their logins will reset). Isn't this something you want to do in the database?

Comment: How can I do it in database? I want Admin folder should be accessed by admin users and the root folder by some users. I am using Windows Authentication

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx) for a starting point for `Asp.net Membership Roles`. (and happy reading, there is a lot of content there).

Comment: That blog is forms authenticaion. I want to do it on Windows Authentication.

Comment: Didn't know you needed that. The default is Forms Authent, which is why the answer is in that style. You didn't say that in your question. Try this: http://forums.asp.net/post/5035109.aspx (this is just for checking the role of the user)

Comment: That post does not help me to add and remove users.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of Windows authentication the ability to use Windows groups and tools to manage users? I simply create an ACL for a group on the web folder and add/remove users in that group.

Comment: Users need to contact the IT department everytime to add and remove users to that application. That is what I am trying to avoid. They should have a page where they can add remove regular users and admin users.

Comment: Or I should figureout how to add and remove users programmatically to a Windows Active Directory Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer. Here is the updated code.

```
protected void UpdateUsers()
{
    Configuration config = (Configuration)WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    AuthorizationSection root_section = (AuthorizationSection)config.GetSection("system.web/authorization");

    //Remove all Current Users to root location.
    root_section.Rules.Clear();

    //Add New Users to root location.
    AuthorizationRule rootAuth = new AuthorizationRule(AuthorizationRuleAction.Allow);
    rootAuth.Users.Add("domain\\rootusername1");
    rootAuth.Users.Add("domain\\rootusername2");
    rootAuth.Users.Add("domain\\rootusername3"); 
    root_section.Rules.Add(rootAuth);

    ////Add Deny All Users to root location.
    AuthorizationRule rootDeny = new AuthorizationRule(AuthorizationRuleAction.Deny);
    rootDeny.Users.Add("*");
    root_section.Rules.Add(rootDeny);

    root_section.CurrentConfiguration.Save();

    //Other Locations  
    ConfigurationLocationCollection section = config.Locations;

    foreach (ConfigurationLocation location in section)
    {
        if (location.Path == "admin") //This is case Sensitive
        {
            Configuration adminConfig = (Configuration)location.OpenConfiguration();
            AuthorizationSection admin_section = (AuthorizationSection)adminConfig.GetSection("system.web/authorization");

            //Remove all Current Users to admin location.
            admin_section.Rules.Clear();

            ////Add New Users to admin location.
            AuthorizationRule adminAuth = new AuthorizationRule(AuthorizationRuleAction.Allow);
            adminAuth.Users.Add("domain\\adminusername1");
            adminAuth.Users.Add("domain\\adminusername2");
            adminAuth.Users.Add("domain\\adminusername3");
            adminAuth.Users.Add("domain\\adminusername4");
            admin_section.Rules.Add(adminAuth);
            adminAuth = null;

            ////Add Deny All Users to root location.
            AuthorizationRule adminDeny = new AuthorizationRule(AuthorizationRuleAction.Deny);
            adminDeny.Users.Add("?"); // For some reason if I remove this line it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
            adminDeny.Users.Add("*");
            admin_section.Rules.Add(adminDeny);

            admin_section.CurrentConfiguration.Save();
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this will be helpfull for someone.

Comment: If the web.config is modified, the web app will reset. If that's a problem, I suggest to use AD groups in web.config and add/remove users for the AD groups.

Comment: Yeah. I understand that. This is a small application and we already have millions of AD groups in our company. I don't want to create one more. Also admins should be able to add remove users and admins without contacting IT department. If I create a AD group they need to contact IT to add remove users and the IT team will not know which group to add the user to because there are millions of AD groups and 100s of applications and serveral team members in IT. All I am trying to do is to make this app maintenance free. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Your IT department should be able to create AD groups that are managed by business admins. Your business users will add/remove users without contracting IT department. But still, depends on your needs and resource, updating web.config maybe just enough.

Comment: Thank you. I was also wondering if I can write code to add remove users from an AD Group.